# what are the different ways read complex test data from csv into JSON requests

Tags: json, csv, karate, karate-call-single

```
[
  {
    "master": {
      "status": "string",
      // more fields
    },
    "address": [
      {
        "place": "string",
        
      // more fields
      }
    ],
    "product": [
      {
        "price": "string",
        // more fields
      }
    ],
    "payment": [
      {
        "action": "string",
        "currency": "string",
        // more fields
      }
    ],
    "referral": [
      {
        "reference": "string",
        // more fields
      }
    ],
    "customer_maintain": {
      "customer_master": {
        "gender": "string",
        // more fields
      },
      "customer_segment": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          // more fields
        }
      ]
    },
    "identification": [
      {
        "idname": "string",
      // more fields
    }
    ]
  
}
]
```

So, if my `JSON` request is this complex and in scenario request I want to read data from a `CSV` file, what are the different and easy ways to do it?

In the Karate feature file, I want to read data from a `CSV` and give it as a `JSON` request for an API.

Comment: a CSV gives you back a JSON array when read in karate. please refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#csv-files

Comment: @PeterThomas I tried "* csv bar = foo" this logic but it is creating flat JSON, not able convert CSV to given previous complex JSON.

what csv is creating:
[
  {
    "master.status": "string",
    "address.place":"string",
    "product.price": "string",
          .
          .

          .
    "identification.idname": "string",
}
]

Comment: yes it will be "flat" json - because csv is a "flat" structure. this answer may give you some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449166/143475 - also note that using embedded expressions, you can replace values in a complex structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272108/143475